# how to stop e.preventDefault() in javascript after getting a successful form validation

Tags: javascript

I want to stop my e.Preventdefault() after a  successful validation of form.  I want to send all the data of form  in mysql.... But just because of e.Preventdefault() i can't send the data to mysql. Form is stuck in the same page.

```
form.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
e.preventDefault();
checkInputs();
successMsg();
```

});

Comment: call `preventDefault` only if `checkInputs` returns false

Answer (score 0):

i assume `checkInputs()` function is returning boolean only for validation so you can place you code in boolean in this manner below

```
form.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
    if(checkInputs() == false){e.preventDefault();}
    else{successMsg();}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this piece of code, I keep it on my side (with credits) :)

Comment: what do u mean ?

Comment: Nothing but thanks, but English is not my native language. So sorry if it is not as clear as it should :)

Comment: well i am confused i have posted this to the post owner and you are thanking me